# Random Numbers in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

What I found was how to create random numbers. Great. This solution, however, was not working in other functions. To create a random number, I used

```
Random randomDirection = new Random();
int directionChoice = randomDirection.Next(1, 4);
```

inside of a function called enemyWalk(){};

However, this caused an error:

> Type 'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and
>   no extension method 'Next' of type 'UnityEngine.Random' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This error does not appear when I take the random integer generator out of the function. Any solutions to fix this problem?

I'm hoping to use this code to make my enemy wander around when not doing anything by randomly choosing an integer that decides which direction he walks (up, left, right, or down), then using a random double generator to determine the distance it walks. However I need a random number generated whenever `enemyWalk(){};` is called.

Comment: When you are using Unity, does it allow you to use the .NET `System.Random` class? If so, you should use it (as Bradley suggests). If not, you should be clear about that in your question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Unity C# the method is as follows

```
Random.Range(minVal, maxVal);
```

See [Unity Documentation - Random](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

The method will accept either integer or float arguments. If using ints `minVal` is **inclusive** and `maxVal` is **exclusive** of the returned random value. In your case it would be:

```
Random.Range(1,4);
```

Instead of `Next(1,4)`.

If using floats, for example

```
Random.Range(1.0F, 3.5F);
```

The return value is also a float, `minVal` and `maxVal` are **inclusive** in this case.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, is there a way to do something like this for float numbers? I'm hoping to get my character to walk 3.5 meters or something along those lines.

Comment: `maxVal` is exclusive for the integer overload of `Range`

Comment: My mistake. Edited. According to the documentation this method supports floats as one of the overloads.

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution would be to just use .NET's `Random` class, which happens to be in the `System` namespace:

```
using System;

...

//Or System.Random without the using
Random randomDirection = new Random();
int directionChoice = randomDirection.Next(1, 5);
```

If you want to use Unity's, call `Range` instead of `Next`:

```
int directionChoice = randomDirection.Range(1, 5);
```

Note that "max" is *exclusive* in both cases, so you should use 5 to return values between 1 and 4 (including 4)

To get random `float`:

```
Random.NextDouble(); //careful, this is between 0 and 1, you have to scale it
//Also, this one is exclusive on the upper bound (1)

Random.Range(1f, 4f); //max is inclusive now
```

Comment: This may seem stupid (I'm new to this, sorry), but I'm not sure I'm using this right. When I insert this I get the same kind of error, but this time it says "The type of namespace name 'Math' could not be found." However, I'm not sure if I need to integrate .NET? Also, I didn't use System.Math anywhere and I'm not sure if I have to.

Comment: @GrantWinney The float version is inclusive, the int version exclusive. It depends which overload is invoked. I believe the int one would in the above case.

Comment: @Jeff If you don't have `using System` at the top, try adding it, or using `System.Math.Random` instead of `Math.Random`. I can't imagine that you aren't *allowed* to use `System` in a Unity project...

Comment: @BradleyDotNet Yeah, that makes sense. using System is allowed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I actually said `System.Math`, but I assumed he had a `using System` at the top. I added that into my code.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So I'll ask you the same question I asked Michael. Any way to do this with floats?

Comment: @Jeff Yep, added it in.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Wow, I must of thought of the Javascript one. You are totally correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, `Random.NextDouble()` is _not_ inclusive. It will never return `1.0`, though it might return something very close (i.e. possibly close enough for the `float` conversion to result in `1.0`). I don't know about the Unity version.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am aware of that, its only inclusive in the Unity version. I'll make sure thats clear.

Comment: @Jeff Why you didn't use `Random.Range(minVal, maxVal);` as mentioned in the other answer?

Comment: @chouaib I'm not sure what you mean, this answer also explains this using Random.Range