# Giving objects unique ids onStart

Tags: c#, .net, random, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of gameObjects that I am assigning unique ids to in the Start function.

```
void Start() {
    UniqueID = String.Format("{0:X}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
}
```

I thought this would work but every now and then I get duplicate ids. How can I make sure that they are always unique?

Comment: use GUID.  Which is unique  globally

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Numbers in Unity3D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161754/random-numbers-in-unity3d)

Comment: According to the MSDN specs on DateTime.Now, it has a resolution of 10 milliseconds. I'd sure hope you are able to generate a whole bunch of GameObjects in that amount of time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unity` already provide an unique id for every object instance, have a look at [GetInstanceID](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html).

Comment: Wow, I did not realise that. That makes everything so much simpler, thank you.

Comment: Get instance ID is only unique to the session. It could end up duplicating itself.

Comment: @Ash Blue: the OP's assigning guid during start, so it should be enough if the last for the current session. You won't get any duplicated id at runtime.

Comment: @Heisenbug Well the problem is Unity only guarantees that the ID will be unique for the session. So if you close and open up Unity again the previously stored instance ID can unintentionally replicate itself. The solution isn't bad, but it creates a larger margin of error than the C# Guid API. If you have a larger project with thousands of objects it's very possible to accidentally replicate an ID via `GetInstanceID`.

Comment: " So if you close and open up Unity again the previously stored instance ID can unintentionally replicate itself". This isn't relevant for the question. The OP didn't ask for saving guids. In addition it makes no sense to save guids across sessions, and this would require more complex [de|serialization] of data [to|from] disk than a simply api call.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a guid.

```
UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString();
```

Using your suggestion, 2 instances running at same time, may apply the same "unique" UniqueID to 2 different objects.

Guid should be unique even across instances.

Comment: Your solution works nicely, thanks. I still don't see how two things can be instantiated at exactly the same time. I thought surely some time would pass between them.

Comment: If the instances where running on a different machine or 2 threads running on different cores maybe?

Comment: @Ogen: Aside from multi-threading, just because time passes doesn't mean the internal clock used by `DateTime.Now` has "ticked". I suggest you try writing a sample program to write out `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in a loop - you may be surprised at how many equal values you get before you next get a different one.

Answer (score 3):

**This method does not provide unique Id across multiple instances of your application!**

I suggest using a `static long` variable and using [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy(v=vs.110).aspx) which handles the concurrency and synchronizing so you can easily assign Id to your objects. It is better than GUID for debugging purposes and more readable, It uses less memory than GUID.

```
//define an accessible static variable somewhere in your code
public static long __Id = 0;

//use it to assign unique Id to objects
UniqueID = Interlocked.Increment(ref __Id);
```

also its performance is better than GUID, here is a quick check and the result

```
public static long __Id = 0;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    sw1.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    sw1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(guid);
    Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedTicks);

    var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
    long id = 0;
    sw2.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        id = Interlocked.Increment(ref __Id);
    }
    sw2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    Console.WriteLine(sw2.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

and the result

> f91419e0-9d3a-4e64-b7fd-ed2080dad599
>   **10376104**  (guid time)
>   10000000
>   **304231**     (long time) 34 times faster than guid

Comment: @DermFrench unfortunately no.