# How to generate a random float using C# in Unity (Unity rejecting most other proposed answers)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Looking to generate a random float but random.range doesn't work since "you need to specify `System.Random()` or `UnityEngine.Random()`". When using System.Random as shown it says "non-invocable member "Random" cannot be used as a method", even though it should be. `UnityEngine.Random()` is a weird device which messes up other random values I'm looking at doing later on.  Getting real sick of unity, program makes simple coding so difficult.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using UnityEngine.UI;


    //using System.Random;

    public class idk : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public float john = 0f;
    public float epic_gaming = 0f; //time variable
    public int gaming;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        epic_gaming += 1;
        if (epic_gaming == 120)
        {
            gaming = System.Random(1,10);
            Debug.Log(gaming);
            epic_gaming = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Indentations might look weird in the code above so that it fits but I assure you it's fine. Thanks in advance.

this isn't the same as the other question posted below, as that question is just about C# (I even read through it before asking mine) while my problem stemmed from Unity's errors/incompatibility with those methods.

Comment: `System.Random` is a class, you need to instantiate it.

Comment: thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: I tried: Random rnd = new System.Random();
 int rndnumber  = rnd.Next(1, 10); but it gave the system.random/unityengine.random error again for the beginning of the line ("Random rnd"). Using the docs.unity3d webpage above doesn't work either since it's outdated and gives the exact same error.

Comment: See my answer on how to solve namespace ambiguity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random Numbers in Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161754/random-numbers-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 4):

```
gaming = Random.Range(1, 10)
```

Random.Range returns an int if you use it with integers.

Doc: [Unity Random.Range()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Also add this to the header: `using static UnityEngine.Random;`

this should solve this: you need to specify System.Random() or UnityEngine.Random()

or use the full namespace like this:

```
gaming = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,10);
```

Comment: It also works with floats if you specify float paramters.

Comment: I specified "public float gaming;"
and then used this: "gaming = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1.1,10.9);" but apparently it only takes ints. How do I change that?

Comment: Specify that you are using a float value like this `gaming = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1.1f,10.9f);`

Comment: ahhhhhhhh I can't believe I didn't see that, thank you so much!

Comment: @Argon Mark the answer accepted if you can still can, the guys marked it as duplicate but actually it was like 2 duplicates :d