# i get any number except 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

This is the code I wrote to spawn something randomly btw two positions but it always spawns it in the "spawnpoint2" and IDK what to do

```
{
public Transform spawnpoint1;
public Transform spawnpoint2;
public GameObject enemyprefab;

private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("spawn", 3f, 5f);
}

void spawn()
{
    float randomizer= Random.Range(0f, 3f);
    if (randomizer == 1f)
        Instantiate(enemyprefab, spawnpoint1);
    else
        Instantiate(enemyprefab, spawnpoint2);
}
```

}

Comment: yes, but can you also send a screenshot of where your script is embedded so I can see what is passed into the script

Comment: It seems pretty small the possibility that you get exactly 1.0 from that random request. Probably you have better results if you use the int version of Random.Range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Numbers in Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161754/random-numbers-in-unity3d)

Comment: Note that you can use inline version of "if": `Instantiate(enemyprefab, randomizer == 1 ? spawnpoint1 : spawnpoint2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis is the float version of the method `Random.Range`. You will have 1.0f sometimes, but it's pretty rare.

You would better use the int version.

```cs
// Random.Range(0f, 3f); // float version
Random.Range(0, 3); // int version
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to get a floating point number between 0 and 3 (inclusive) there is really a small possibility to get exactly 1.0 between all the possibile intermediate values.
You should use the integer version from Random.Range, but this version has the upper limit excluded so you should use 4 as the upper limit to get any value from 0 to 3
While it seems secondary (you check only for 1 so you will get the 1 even if the upper limit were 2) using an upper limit of 3 changes the frequences of 1 results vs other numbers and so your spawnpoint1 will be more frequent.

```
void spawn()
{
    int randomizer= Random.Range(0, 4);
    if (randomizer == 1)
        Instantiate(enemyprefab, spawnpoint1);
    else
        Instantiate(enemyprefab, spawnpoint2);
}
```