# Integrating random values in Unity3d works incorrectlly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, integration

I have simple script:

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

public class DLATEST : MonoBehaviour
 {
     int wx = 0;
     
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         wx += Random.Range(-1, 1);
         
         Debug.Log(wx);
     }
 }
```

but I have weird results: 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8

wx slowly declines to negatives until it overflows.

I expect that wx  will have values near 0 and slowly change around it, but not decline as it have. This is simple numerical integration but it works incorrectly.

I have also tried this code:

```
int wx = 0;
int wxPrev = 0;
 
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     wx = wxPrev + Random.Range(-1, 1);
     
     Debug.Log(wx);
     wxPred = wx;
 }
```

Results are the same.

If I debug Random.Range(-1, 1) only then everything is ok, random values are random.

What is wrong in my code? Thank you.

Comment: [Read the second declaration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Comment: You probably meant to use `Random.Range(-1f,1f);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Numbers in Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161754/random-numbers-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Random.Range(int x, int y) the result will be >= x && < y

[image: Random int]

In your case Random.Range(-1,1) always returns -1 or 0.
You probably needed Random.Range(-1f,1f) - to force using Random.Range(float,float) instead of random int or change to Random.Range(-1,2) so it woult return integer -1, 0 or 1 randomly

Comment: Yes, you are I right!
Random.Range(-1, 2) returns -1 0 1 int`s and integration works as supposed.

Thanks!